# Can I scrape the next page with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been suffering from a problem for a day. I want to crawl the website which has pages.
I found that I can crawl it when each pages has different urls
justlike (page=1 . page=2 .. .etc)..
But the website I'm trying to scrape, It never changes its url even though I go to next page .
Is there any ways to scrape this kind of page? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

the code is the result curl into python

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'WMONID': 'smDC5Ku5TeX',
    'userId': 'robin9634',
    'UID': 'robin9634',
    'JSESSIONID': 'lLqLdHFEk4iEJdQ2HCR5m05tg6ZIxBdegEamDzxeEoTClkvqVDN4xzXeMPtTIN3e.cG9ydGFsX2RvbWFpbi9wZDU=',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://dhlottery.co.kr',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://dhlottery.co.kr/gameInfo.do?method=powerWinNoList',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

params = (
    ('method', 'powerWinNoList'),
)

data = {
  'nowPage': '7',
  'searchDate': '20200909',
  'calendar': '2020-09-09',
  'sortType': 'num'
}

response = requests.post('https://dhlottery.co.kr/gameInfo.do', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)

#NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
#reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
#in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.post('https://dhlottery.co.kr/gameInfo.do?method=powerWinNoList', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

Comment: The page in question seems to require logging in, so I can't confirm this, but I imagine it uses an AJAX-ish request to get the subsequent pages. Look in your browser's developer tools, in the Network panel, to see what happens when you navigate between pages. You may be able to use those requests as your guide.

Comment: I did just like you've said, go to the network panel and clicked each pages. How can I see those differences?

Comment: If you click open each request, you'll see how they are made in the side bar. Pay attention to the posted data, and the response too. You can also right-click -> copy as Fetch to get (JavaScript) code you can adapt to a `requests` request.

Comment: if you copy as `cURL` code then you can convert to Python on page https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: i think i've found the difference between page 5 and 7



 "body": "nowPage=7&searchDate=20200909&calendar=2020-09-09&sortType=num",
 "body": "nowPage=5&searchDate=20200909&calendar=2020-09-09&sortType=num",


 
i want to actually adapt it into my code. how can i?

Comment: you didn't show code so don't expect example code for this. Probably it is `POST` request and you can use `requests.post(..., data=...)`

Comment: yeah.. I edited again.. I really need help.